# How to prevent ad blockers from restricting sections of my website (non google ads)

Tags: theming, blocks

I have a block towards the header, that is full width, and has some basic HTML with Full HTML Text format.

It is getting blocked by my user's ad blocker software. so far it is reported to be blocked with [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=en-US) and [Adguard](https://adguard.com/en/welcome.html). I have tested and verified with [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=en-US)

My content isn't "spamy" at all. In fact it is a coupon code so they are missing out :)

Here's the content

```
<h2 style="text-align: center; font-weight: 300;">50% OFF entire store. Use code <strong>AWESOMESALE50</strong></h2>
```

The CSS class for the block is **banner-advert**

Could it be the inline CSS?

Comment: From my very lil knowledge about this topic, it usually blocks something that has the word "ad" or if your wrapper has an id or class of "ad".

Comment: interesting theory, I just updated my post to include the CSS class. It does include "advert" I'm going to change and test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [No Sssweat's simple suggestion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236071/how-to-prevent-ad-blockers-from-restricting-sections-of-my-website-non-google-a#comment289792_236071), it is fixed (as far as I can tell).

I changed my CSS class for the block from "`banner-advert`" to "`sitewide-promo`".

I'm assuming either `banner` or `advert` caused an issue, so I replaced both.

Comment: I think you should mark your own answer as accepted, that way it is no longer considered as "unanswered" ...